# Expose private Docker registry inside Kubernetes cluster at path `/registry`

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, kubernetes-ingress

I have a private Docker registry inside a Kubernetes 1.13 cluster exposed by a Kubernetes NGINX ingress controller 0.23.0 and the following `Ingress` object:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: my-name
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: registry
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /?(.*)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my-domain
    secretName: my-secret
```

This allows me to pull an existing image as follows:

```
docker image pull my-cluster/my-image
```

I would not now change the setup such that the registry is exposed at `my-cluster/registry`. How can this be done, and is it even possible?

Changing `path` to `/registry/?(.*)` did not do the trick. `docker login my-cluster/registry` now produces the following error message and `docker image pull my-cluster/registry/my-image` also does not work. My current guess as to the root cause is that the registry also also use the prefix `registry` (as configured in the `Ingress`) for its internal redirects. If applicable, how can this be configured (preferably in the `Ingress` too)?

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://my-cluster/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now concluded that referring to a Docker registry by a URL-like location (such as `my-cluster/registry`) as opposed to a host-like location (such as `my-cluster` with an optional port) is not possible.

So I'll reserve a separate IP address and certificate for `registry.my-cluster` and proceed with that.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar issue, i'm trying to expose the registryui with nginx ingress on a /registry path.

first, I succeeded to expose with this configuration nginx :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: registry-ingress
  namespace: devops
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - registry.host.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-staging
  rules:
  - host: registry.host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: registry-ui
          servicePort: 8080
```

on the other hand when I try expose the service with a path, I only have the home page that works, as I try to navigate in a sub page (a page of an image) I have a 404 error.

```
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - host.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-staging
  rules:
  - host: host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /registry
        backend:
          serviceName: registry-ui
          servicePort: 8080
```

i wanted to know how did you come to the conclusion that it's impossible to have a host/regitry links working?

cordially thank you

Comment: Your service is called `registry-ui`. Are you running the actual registry there or a UI that sits on top? If it's a registry could you please show an `image pull` command where you get an image from the URL with suffix `/registry`. Thanks.

Comment: im using 2 docker images : 
      - image: registry:2 --> with nodeport 30400
        name: registry 
      - image: hyper/docker-registry-web:latest
        name: registryui --> with ingress on 8080
and i'm facing a problem with the ui, and i will certainly have the same issues with the 5000 port of the registry

Comment: did u use the ui for the registry ?

Comment: No, I did not use a URI yet. Is there an "official" version. I don't doubt that it's possible to expose the UI at a URI with a suffix such as "/registry", but I still have doubts about the registry itself.